# Добавить автоинкремент в столбец с Primary_key в SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть существующая таблица, где первый столбец [ID] - PK. Как добавить в него автоинкремент? Прочитал общий тезис о том, что таблицу нужно пересобирать (то есть, так просто не "включишь"), но не могу составить скрипт.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE table_name ( field_name int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, ... )`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column

Comment: с внешними ключами еще разобраться надо, если есть. Вообще в SSMS можно в дизайнере изменить что надо, и нажать "generate scripts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если лень пересобирать таблицу, добавьте *sequence*.

Есть, к примеру, таблица с данными:

```
CREATE TABLE [Some] (ID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Some PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO [Some] VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

добавляем последовательность и назначаем значением по умолчанию на столбец:

```
BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @nextID int;
    SELECT @nextID = COALESCE(MAX(ID), 0) + 1 FROM [Some] WITH (TABLOCKX);

    EXEC('CREATE SEQUENCE Some_ID AS INT START WITH ' + @nextID);

    ALTER TABLE [Some]
        ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Some_ID DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR Some_ID) FOR ID;

COMMIT
```

---

Если принципиально `IDENTITY` (например, планируете пользоваться функциями `@@IDENTITY` или `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`), то придётся повозиться.

Вариант с `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH TO` будет предпочтительным на большом количестве данных (мне он нравится и на небольшом количестве данных тоже).

Нужно создать таблицу в точности с той же структурой (включая индексы и ограничения), но со столбцом `IDENTITY`:

```
CREATE TABLE [Some2] (ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Some2 PRIMARY KEY);
```

потом перекинуть данные, удалить старую таблицу, а новую переименовать в старую:

```
BEGIN TRAN

    -- здесь нужно удалить FK-ограничения ссылающиеся на таблицу [Some]

    ALTER TABLE [Some] SWITCH TO [Some2];

    DROP TABLE [Some];

    EXEC sp_rename 'Some2', 'Some', 'OBJECT';
    EXEC sp_rename 'PK_Some2', 'PK_Some', 'OBJECT';

    -- здесь нужно восстановить FK-ограничения ссылающиеся на таблицу [Some]

    DBCC CHECKIDENT('Some');

COMMIT
```

На самом деле `SWITCH TO` не перемещает данные, а лишь изменяет метаинформацию, переназначая области данных, занятые таблицей, с одной таблицы на другую.

Этим же способом можно проделать и обратную операцию, если `IDENTITY`, наоборот, нужно убрать со столбца.

Answer (score 0):

Заходим в таблицу:

```
SELECT * FROM table

set foreign_key_checks=0;
ALTER TABLE artikel MODIFY COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: Ответ появился через 6 лет после предыдущего) Вполне вероятно даже, что таки появилась возможность в SQL Server добавить авто-инкремент "на лету" :D Но я уже много лет в Oracle, да и вообще столько воды уже утекло, что чувствую себя постаревшим :)